# Can anyone explain to me the behavior of a nested for loop in Java in regards to memory?

Tags: java, for-loop

Let's suppose I have this code which also print a pattern of star (that is if I replace the string literal in side the print method with "#") like a staircase going from right to left below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    for (int i=0; i <= 6; i++){
        for(int k=0; k < i; k++){
            System.out.print("This is k:"+k + " " + " This is i:"+i);
        }

        System.out.println();
    }


}
```

This will actually prints all 0s for the values of k in each column, then 
prints all 1s, then all 2s etc...For the value of i it will print in each column  1,2,3,4,5,6 then 2,3,4,5,6 the 3,4,5,6 etc..

Ok, why is the value of i does not start at zero here? I thought the inside loop is supposed to execute first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with memory, just logic. Because `k` starts at `0`, and `k < i` means the first test is `0 < 0` which isn't true. So `i` increments. Thus your first `i` output is `1`. If you want to see `0` for `i`, you need `k <= i` in your inner `for` loop condition.

Comment: I know it's logic but that's not the question I asked.Everything in coding has something to do with memory. If you can' t answer just don't reply.

Comment: @user5604281 When `i` is `0`, your loop condition tests `0 < 0` which is false. Thus the second loop isn't entered. Which is what I said in my answer. Good luck with your studies.

Comment: Seems like I didn't ask the question correctly. Let me rephrase my question. Ok, which block of code get executed first and why? I understand the inside loop has to be finished before the statement in the outer loop gets executed but does the inner loop prints all 0's first then the code goes all the way to the outer loop again to check for the condition again?

Comment: The inner loop isn't entered at all when `i` is `0`. Because you test `0 < 0` which is false. So it is not entered. If you change `k < i` to `k <= i` then it will be entered.

Comment: Yes, I get that. Keep going what happens next? Please explain the whole process from top to bottom. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this you should start your value of `i from 1`

```
for(i=1;i<6;i++)
```

As you are not achieving anything with `i=0` except `println`.